# How to repeatedly un tar files that are within the tar itself

Tags: shell, tar

I have a tar file that has been tar-ed many times. It follows a similar structure like this:

```
1000.tar
  |
   --- filler.txt (random text)
       999.tar
         |
          --- filler.txt
              998.tar

                ...
```

How can I write a command/piece of code to get the final .txt of the tar structure? 
I can do this by hand `tar -xf 1000.tar`, but it's more efficient to use code.

I'm thinking the code should go like this:

```
for i in range 1000, 1:
   tar -xf string(i) + ".tar"
```

Comment: Extract to the current directory and use `seq` or brace expansion. Btw, is this from some sort of challenge?

Comment: @Panki yeah, it is. So i would just do `tar -xf seq 1 1000 1 .tar`, or something similar?

Comment: Almost ;) See my answer below.

Comment: Is the numbering of the `.tar` files fixed or do you have to extract as long as you find another `.tar` file inside the previous one? Does every `.tar` file contain at most one `.tar`file? Do you want to throw away the `filler.txt` files or other files contained in the outer `.tar` files? Please [edit] your question to add more details. This will make the question and answer(s) more helpful for others.

Comment: I've never _ever_ seen a `tar` archive inside another `tar` archive more than two levels deep. Still, this issue seems to crop up with surprising frequency here on U&L.

Comment: @Kusalananda Matryoshka ;) Seen that in "hacking" competitions. Our Kali friends...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro As if hacking had anything to do with extracting obnoxious `tar` archives...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro its supposedly "forensics"

Comment: @Kusalananda That is a common and simple challenge as part of a hacking contest, be it in hackerank, or security meetings. This one is more convoluted: https://dos.sh/blog/matryoshka ; but you are supposed to do them by yourself  and not ask U&L, that is why is a challenge.

Comment: @AminKaric Yeah, that is the correct term...I prefer doing puzzles on my own, more fun.

Comment: What is the stand of U&L on this? Should question like this be answered vaguely ('challenge to the reader')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple `bash` for loop should do what you need:

```
for i in {1000..1}; do tar -xf $i.tar; done
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks so much! Btw, my directory has a size quota, but i can just make it so it deletes the original tar after.

Comment: You don't have to extract the archive at all if you know what to look for. The archives are not compressed, so the files inside it would be (mostly) readable.

Comment: @Kusalananda how? I thought of `tar --list`, but I don't think that can recurse into sub-tars. How would you get to the final `file` without untarring the parents?

Comment: @terdon Create a `tar` archive of a text file, then look at it in an editor or something (`strings` maybe). If you know what you're looking for, all you need is a simple `awk` program to get the last text in the archive of archives.

Comment: @Kusalananda Nice! I had no idea. Just posted an answer with that approach, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive approach that doesn't require you to know the filenames of the tarballs in advance. Put the file in a directory that contains nothing else. Then, assuming all the tarballs contained in the parent archive have a `.tar` extension, you can simply do:

```
file=(*tar); while [[ -e $file ]]; do tar xf "$file"; rm "$file"; file=(*tar); done
```

#### Explanation

- `file=(*tar);` : set the variable `$file` to contain the file name. There should be only one file that matches the `*tar` glob in the directory you run this in.
- `while [[ -e $file ]]; do` : while `$file` exists...
- `tar xf $file; rm "$file"; file=(*tar);` : untar the current value of `$file`, then delete the tarball you just extracted, and finally set the `$file` variable to the name of the new, now only, tar file in the directory.

---

And here's an even more direct approach ([thanks @kusalananda!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545543/how-to-repeatedly-un-tar-files-that-are-within-the-tar-itself/545546?noredirect=1#comment1011984_545546)). I made the `tar` archive using these commands:

```
$ cat file 
This is the text!
$ file=file; for i in {1..1000}; do tar cf $i.tar $file; file=$i.tar; done
```

So this is a file called `file` which contains the text `This is the text!\n`. The `file` has been tarred 1000 times and we now have `1000.tar`. We can print the original text out with:

```
$ awk -F'\0' '/[^\0]/{print $(NF)}' 1000.tar 
This is the text!
```

Note that that isn't actually the original text. The original newline was eaten by `tar` but replaced by `awk`. To get the real value from the archive, you'd need (the last `$` there is my prompt, there was no newline):

```
$ awk -F'\0' '/[^\0]/{printf "%s", $NF}' 1000.tar 
This is the text!$
```

In this particular case, I was able to recreate the file name as well by telling `awk` to print the last field (`$NF`), and the 438th field before the last one:

```
awk -F'\0' '/[^\0]/{print $(NF) >$(NF-438)}' 1000.tar
```

That created a new `file` with the contents of the original. So the same thing as extracting. However, I don't know if the `-428` is a magic number. `tar` seems to add multiple NULLs in its archive, so I found that by running:

```
$ awk -F'\0' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~ /file/){print i,NF-i}}}' 1000.tar 
434674 438
```

That told me that field 434674 had the contents `file` and that is 438 fields before the final one.

If your `awk` supports `gsub`, you can probably make it more general with:

```
awk -F'\0' '/[^\0]/{gsub(/\0+/,"\0"); print $NF > $(NF-11)}' 1000.tar
```