# How to repeatedly unpack tar.gz files that are within the tar.gz itself

Tags: bash, shell-script, tar

There is a file with the name `**flag_999.tar.gz**` which has been packed maybe 999 times is there any way of unpacking all of them or a bash script because nothing is working for me.

The name is the file goes as flag_999.tar.gz and inside the archive, there is flag_998.tar.gz and inside that there is flag_997.tar.gz. So here the "flag_" is constant and then the number goes descending
I reached flag_967.tar.gz manually to check the file names inside.

I tried:

```
file=(*tar); while [[ -e $file ]]; do tar zxf "$file"; rm "$file"; file=(*tar); done
```

no output

```
awk -F'\0' '/[^\0]/{print $(NF)}' flag_999.tar.gz
```

output not readable

```
for i in {1000..1}; do tar -xf $i.tar; done
```

maybe this could work I don't know because I don't know how to use it.

Click here to see and download the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ycWVR0htwFyexCJRohTGHio4UFdvGuPW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeatedly un tar files that are within the tar itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545543/how-to-repeatedly-un-tar-files-that-are-within-the-tar-itself)

Comment: You will have to use `-xzf` instead of `-xf` obviously

Comment: no tried them all

Comment: Unlikely, and even if you did, you should edit your question and provide the details of what you tried and how it failed

Comment: What I flagged as dupe is the solution - you just need to do a little transfer exercise, because your files are named differently. Also, you should try to understand what it does, not blindly copy-paste and execute it.

Comment: the name is flag_999 and the tar inside has the name flag_998 and inside that it is flag_997 and so on. so here the "flag_" is constant and then the number goes descending

Answer (score 1):

With the GNU implementation of `tar`, you could write an `extract` script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
PROGNAME="$0" exec tar -zxvvf - --to-command='
  case "$TAR_FILENAME" in
    (*.tar.gz | *.tgz) exec "$PROGNAME";;
    (*) set -o noclobber
        mkdir -p -- "$(dirname -- "$TAR_FILENAME")" &&
          exec cat > "$TAR_FILENAME"
  esac' 3<&-
```

To be invoked as:

```
path/to/extract < flag_999.tar.gz
```

in your case.

That script will call itself recursively via `tar`'s `--to-command` for each archive member whose name ends in `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`. It will extract files on the fly without storing the intermediate tar files on disk.

Note that it only extracts regular files and doesn't restore any file metadata.

Comment: Sorry I tried the above script but it didn't work.

Comment: @farzan In which way did it not work?

Comment: @farzan, FWIW, that script *works* for me (in that it eventually extracts the contents of `flag.txt`) on your file with GNU `tar` 1.34 on Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: ./script.sh: 2: exec: /home/rasiq/Downloads/flag_999.tar.gz: Permission denied
 Even after chmod +x

Comment: @farzan, did you start it as `./script.sh < /home/rasiq/Downloads/flag_999.tar.gz`? Though even if you didn't, I can't see how you could get that error message with this script as written.

Comment: If you are able to access the contents of the file then could you please Email me the attachment at rasiqsofi@protonmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

This weird file was a nice stress test for [ratarmount](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount). It basically works out of the box with the `--recursive` option but has the problem that the file path grows too long to something like `mountpoint/flag_998.tar.gz/flag_997.tar.gz/flag_996.tar.gz/flag_995.tar.gz/flag_994.tar.gz/...`. To avoid that, I added a more generic command line option to the existing `--strip-recursive-tar-extension` so that you can now transform the mount point of a recursive tar arbitrarily by using `--transform-recursive-mount-point`. This is currently not yet fully released but you can already try it out like this:

```bsh
python3 -m pip install --user --force-reinstall 'git+https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount.git@develop#egginfo=ratarmountcore&subdirectory=core'
python3 -m pip install --user 'git+https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount.git@develop#egginfo=ratarmount'

ratarmount --recursive --transform-recursive-mount-point '.*/' '' flag_999.tar.gz mountpoint
ls -lA mountpoint
# drw-r--r-- 1 root root    146 May 24  2019 flag_0.tar.gz
# drw-r--r-- 1 root root  17331 May 24  2019 flag_100.tar.gz
# drw-r--r-- 1 root root  17490 May 24  2019 flag_101.tar.gz
# drw-r--r-- 1 root root  17652 May 24  2019 flag_102.tar.gz
ls -lA mountpoint/flag_0.tar.gz/
# -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33 May 24  2019 flag.txt
cat mountpoint/flag_0.tar.gz/flag.txt
```

And there you have it. If everything works correctly, your original archive basically contains only some kind of hexadecimal hash inside a single file.